# A shortcut to create AppWidget

Tags: android, android-appwidget

I created an AppWidget and put it on the market. Two users send me as feedback : "please create a shortcut that let us add more widget easily"

I actually have no idea if that's possible, and no idea how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

*Just guess*

If it is possible to create multiple instances of your widget (like weather for different places) you can try to add "+" button somewhere on widget, and create new instance nearby. But I'm not sure if it will be really useful for most users.

Comment: Alright, my question then : how can I create a new instance of a widget programmatically ? Because : if i add a + button, what should happen ?